# Show conflicts when pulling using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm using libgit2sharp to pull (`Commands.Pull`) from a remote repo using the default `FetchOptions`, `MergeOptions` and `PullOptions`. My working directory has an uncommitted change that will cause a conflict, and as expected I get a `CheckOutConflictException` with the message "1 conflict prevents checkout".

What I can't figure out is how to programmatically find out the file that is causing the conflict. `repo.Index.Conflicts` doesn't contain any conflicts, I haven't found any documentation for this case in the [wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-pull), and I can't find any tests for this case in the [codebase](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/53900ea76d89b77bd70ca8cb5c2168afe9e36f52/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/NetworkFixture.cs).

Can anyone show me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a [`CheckoutOptions.OnCheckoutNotify`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/CheckoutOptions.cs#L26) callback, which will notify you every time checkout encounters a path with a particular action.

In this case, you want to look for conflicts, so set your [`CheckoutOptions.CheckoutNotifyFlags`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/CheckoutOptions.cs#L20) to listen for [`CheckoutNotifyFlags.Conflict`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/3f9b415fa1edfc31ce1ec2b4b3d18441c34adfff/LibGit2Sharp/CheckoutNotificationOptions.cs#L20).

You will be called back for each file that has a checkout conflict and given the path.